# How do i get relevant Information from a Webpage (HTML) into my Android App?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, android-asynctask

at first i have to say that my english isnt the best so dont blame me for that:).

I want to create a Food-App for Android-Systems which is able to get Information (like ingredients,preperation) of Webpages by downloading them through an Asynctask and saving them into a Database (SQLite).

I learned to work with JSON - based website and to show the results(after downloading the data) in a ListView. Now i have the problem that i dont have JSON in front of me and i have really no clue about how i can write a code which extracts relevant information of HTML - Webpage. Is it even possible?

Sorry if maybe of u may laugh now how unknowing i am but i try to learn:)

So i basically know much about Asynctask and Databases. But the point is i dont know how to connect them all with my specific problem.

Thank you in advance for all who will deal with my topic!

Comment: Here is another great example using `jsoup` to get elements from html - http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Comment: The reason `JSON` works better for this is because if you use `jsoup` you will have to create a `html` page for each receipt. When you use `JSON` you can use one file to get all the receipts/ingredients directly from your database, or even enter all the data (ingredients/preperations) directly in the `JSON` file. I would recommend you not to use the `jsoup` approach, not saying its not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Try working with `jsoup` .  [Here](https://jsoup.org/) you can find the jsoup library and full source code.

See an example at this site: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/jsoup/article.html

---

Add `jsoup` to your project by adding this line to your **app build.gradle** :

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a XML based presentation of pages.

You can parse it with DOM, if theres repeated tags you may find easier to parse with SAX. But you will need to parse every information on the site and navigate trough the graph to extract what you want.